# Run command in bash_profile only when in MINGW64

Tags: windows-10, bash, .bash-profile, git-bash

I am using git bash, and in my `.bash_profile` I have

```
cd
```

Which works when I start `MINGW64`, but when I open vscode, the console also runs that command. Is there any way for me to only run the `cd` command when in `MINGW64`?

For example (I am not a bash programer, so I'm not sure if this syntax is correct):

```
if [current = MINGW64]; then
  cd
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git for Windows uses MINGW64/MSYS, and typically there will be an environment variable MSYSTEM defined when you start your shell. You can just [check if it's defined](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/083), like this:

```
if [[ $MSYSTEM = "MINGW64" ]] ; then
  cd
fi
```

Comment: I have now been using this for a few days, and it looks like it is working